# Discord.js V12: How do you remove a role from everybody that has it at once

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I found this thread here [How to remove a role from every member of the guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383129/how-to-remove-a-role-from-every-member-of-the-guild) but when I tried the answer someone gave I got an error in the "." of the .then and I tried a different route.

```js
const EEEE = '153587203488874496';
let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('766141415759151154').members;
if (message.author.id === EEEE)
 membersWithRole.roles.remove('766141415759151154');
message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} kicks you out of their room`);
```

Now with this I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined" so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that `membersWithRole.roles` is undefined, which is true. Calling [`.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) on a role (like you did with `message.guild.roles.cache.get('766141415759151154').members;`) returns a [Collection of GuildMembers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members). If you want to remove a role for each GuildMember, you can use the [`Collection.prototype.each`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) method. See the example code below and give it a try:

```js
membersWithRole.each((memberWithRole) => {
  memberWithRole.roles.remove('766141415759151154');
});
```